# Cómo podría saber el ancho de un texto dibujado con .fillText()

Tags: javascript, canvas

¿Cómo puedo medir el ancho de un `drawText`, para que la imagen (`drawImage`) se dibuje al lado de la última letra del texto?

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    var cadena = prompt('Dibuja aquí lo que desees', '');
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(cadena, 10, 50);
    var obj = {
      simbolo: new Image()
    }

    obj.simbolo.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkbdf.png";

    ctx.drawImage(obj.simbolo, 0, 0);

  });
</script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [**`CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText(string)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) devuelve un objeto cuya propiedad [`.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics/width) es el ancho en píxeles del texto.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  //Texto
  var cadena = prompt('Dibuja aquí lo que desees', '');
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var posInicial = { x: 10, y: 50 };

  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(cadena, posInicial.x, posInicial.y);

  //Obtenemos el acho:
  var ancho = ctx.measureText(cadena).width;
  console.log('Ancho:', ancho, 'píxeles.');

});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

---

Luego, antes de dibujar la imagen, deberías esperar a que esté cargada (evento [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/es-es/docs/Web/Events/load)).

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  //Texto
  var cadena = prompt('Dibuja aquí lo que desees', '');
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var posInicial = { x: 10, y: 50 }
  
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(cadena, posInicial.x, posInicial.y);
  //Imagen
  var obj = {
    simbolo: new Image()
  }
  obj.simbolo.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkbdf.png";

  obj.simbolo.addEventListener("load", function() {
    //Obtenemos el acho:
    var ancho = ctx.measureText(cadena).width;
    //Dibujamos la imagen
    ctx.drawImage(obj.simbolo, posInicial.x + ancho, 0);
  });

});
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="350" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score -2):

Si pruebas obtener el ancho del elemento usando offsetWidth.

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth
```

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth